# {% if page.left_sidebar %} region showing on nodes but not view

Tags: 8

I have a template page--about.html.twig that is being extended by page--recreation.html.twig everything else is the same and when I look in inspector it everything is correct the only this is my left sidebar region is not printing in the extended theme. The theme is being used by a view /recreation

then I have

```
  {% if page.left_sidebar %}
        {% block left_sidebar %}
          <aside class="col-sm-3 left-aside" role="complementary">
            {{ page.left_sidebar }}
          </aside>
        {% endblock %}
      {% endif %}
```

maybe it won' display because it is a view /recreation and I am using a page template but that is the template it is suggesting for me it is suggesting the same template name for my content type called 'recreation' and view called 'recreation' it prints on the node but not the view.

Comment: It is obvious, that `page.left_sidebar` is empty at this point, if both the condition and the output say so. How the content of this region gets lost is difficult to say. Have you checked it all the way from block layout, some debugging php code or in other page templates (page.html.twig, page--about.html.twig)?

Comment: I will check with debug thanks.  It's not empty it's outputting on another page using the same template, and it outputs also using the template that it extends

Comment: output from kint for page--about is $this->getAttribute(page array(0)

Comment: I would simplify the problem. Remove the name collision by renaming the view to a different name. And avoid the twig block by copying the complete page template for testing only. Not saying that there is anything wrong with the twig block, I used this many times, never had any issues, but usually my blocks are bigger and include the if statements.

Comment: I can't change the view path, need it to be at path /recreation, I copied the complete template and no change.

Comment: I changed the path to recreation--overview so it is now using page--recreation--overview, I copied the complete template and no change.

Comment: So I did both these things and still no left sidebar region, most have something to do with it being a view not a page? because left sidebar displays on node recreation and all other nodes.

Comment: I tried printing a different region and still nothing it must have to do with that it's a menu block I am trying to print on a view page

Comment: Your last remark seems to point in the right direction. Probably the problem is in the config of the menu block, how the menu is configured in relation to the url of the page.

Comment: the problem was checkbox show on content type. thanks its fixed now.